# Serial execution of test cases on chrome and firefox using WebDriverIO with multiremote

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

WebdriverIO allows you to run multiple WebDriver/Appium sessions in a single test using multiremote feature.
Suppose I want to test a chat functionality on chrome and firefox as well(Both should run serially). For second browser, I can use another browser (say chrome, giving it another name: mychromebrowser2).

How should I structure the WDIO Testrunner file, so that I will able to run chat test case, first on chrome, then on firefox, and using same mychromebrowser2 as another browser to send the chat message.

Comment: multiremote will run the same test case on both browsers? I dont think you will be able to control what should run based on type of browser? I remember seeing something in linkedin about doing this through mobiles.

Comment: I am definitely sure, I can handle the second browser, by using :
capabilities: {
        myChromeBrowser: {
            capabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome'
            }
        },
        mysecondChromeBrowser: {
            capabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome'
            }
        }
    },
But if I want to run the same feature test case for firefox also, I am not able to do so.